# Formatting div in partials using bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Total newb question: I've created a partial for calling 3 of the same div per row. The div is dynamic tho so I feel I shouldn't have to repeat the same code 3 times. How can I condense this with loops?

**Product Index**

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render 'products/product' %>
</div>
```

**Product Partial**

```
<div class="row">
    <h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>
    <% @products.each do |category, products| %>
      <h3><%= category.name %></h3>
      <% products.each do |product| %>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag product.default_image.path %>
              </div>
          <div class="caption">
                <h4><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.permalink) %></h4>
                <p><%= product.short_description %></p>
                <p><b>Price:</b> <%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div></div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag product.default_image.path %>
              <div class="caption">
                <h4><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.permalink) %></h4>
                <p><%= product.short_description %></p>
                <p><b>Price:</b> <%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div></div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag product.default_image.path %>
              <div class="caption">
                <h4><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.permalink) %></h4>
                <p><%= product.short_description %></p>
                <p><b>Price:</b> <%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div></div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Aren't you showing the same product 3 times?

Comment: @DVG Yes, I'm trying to show the different products with this type of dynamic div, just having trouble setting it up so that it sets 3 different products per row

Comment: I'd say take that div and make it a partial, and pass it the product. Then, use each_with_index and use the index value to close the row and open a new one every third product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.html.erb:

```
<h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>
<%= render @products %>`
```

then have a `_product.html.erb` which just has the info for one product and rails will know what you want to do:

```
<div class="row">
 <h3><%= product.category.name %></h3>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="thumbnail">
  <%= image_tag product.default_image.path %>
 </div>
 ....
```

check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials. Look for the sub-header: `rendering collections`.